# Concatenating two NSStrings separated by a CRLF

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

Sorry for the dumb question.  I have two NSStrings and I want to create a third that is the first string plus a new line plus the second string.  I know this must be easy but I am banging my head looking for it.

Ultimately I want the resulting string to display correctly in a table view cell.

Regards

Dave

Comment: "...but I am banging my head looking for it." Not to be overly rude, but did you try banging it in the documentation? http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW21

Comment: I did, and still couldn't find the \r\n that was the missing part of the puzzle.  I am finding the documentation pretty tricky at times, it seems if I know what I am looking for (i.e., the class and the method name) then it is fairly easy to find and work out what to do.  Knowing the right class/method in the first place seems to be down to experience and time working with the SDK and I am new to most of these concepts.  Hopefully I will be beyond the dumb question stage soon.

Regards Dave

Comment: Ah, okay. I read the title as meaning you were having trouble concatenating, rather than having trouble representing CRLF. Here's the full list of escape sequences: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/escape_sequences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You best bet is to use `stringWithFormat:`

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n%@", firstString, secondString];
```

When putting this into a table cell, you might have to set the `numberOfLines` property and override the `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

And don't for get to release you strings when done.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your code! You would probably write "\r\n" (CRLF)

Comment: Thanks guys, life saver.  Up against it at the moment fixing niggles within my code :o)

Answer (score 6):

For an arbitrary number of strings, put them in an array and send it a `componentsJoinedByString:` message, passing the CRLF string (`@"\r\n"`).